# Which lens is mounted in this D800?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d800

I have found this pic of Nikon D800 and I would like to know which lens is mounted on it. I dont know whether its Nikkor or not. Here is the pic.

[image: D800]

Somebody kindly help me to identify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [AF-S VR Nikkor 200mm f/2 II telephoto lens](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-nikkor-200mm-f%252f2g-ed-vr-ii.html)

[image]

You can get some extra details on [Ken Rockwell's review](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/200mm-f2-vr-ii.htm)